# How to do a bulk insert with node-postgres

Tags: postgresql, express, node-postgres

I am importing an excel file into a postgres database with express and node-pg

Currently I am looping through the excel rows and executing an insert for every row but I feel it's not the right way:

```
workbook.xlsx.readFile(excel_file).then(function () {
        // get the first worksheet          
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        // Loop through all rows
        worksheet.eachRow(function (row, rowNumber) {
            // Commit to DB only from line 2 and up. We want to exclude headers from excel file
            if (rowNumber > 1) {
                // Loop through all values and build array to pass to DB function
                row.eachCell(function (cell, colNumber) {
                    arrSQLParams.push(cell.value)                   
                })

                // Add the user id from session to the array
                arrSQLParams.push(user);

                // Insert into DB
                db.query(strSQL, arrSQLParams, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                            ret = false;
                        }
                })

                // Empty the array for new query
                arrSQLParams = [];
            }
        })          
    });
```

Is there a better way to do this to improve performance?

Comment: Since you asking about the performance, what is the maximum number of rows you may need to insert at a time, and approximate size of each row? To put otherwise - is it small enough to get all the data into Node.js memory at once?

Comment: About 1000 rows at a time

Comment: In that case the best way to do it is via [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) and its [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) type. I can throw in an example later on, if you really need it, but it is basically all here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise. That's what you need for really good performance and flexibility at the same time ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008668/bulk-insert-into-postgres-with-brianc-node-postgres/44757056#44757056

Answer (score 6):

Following the clarification provided by the author, to insert up to 1000 records at a time, the solution as suggested within [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise) is exactly what the author needs, in terms of both performance and flexibility.

**UPDATE**

A must-read article: [Data Imports](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-essential. It will apply a patch on node-postgres and You just need to call it's executeBulkInsertion function. You can create an array of the objects to be inserted and pass it to the 
executeBulkInsertion function.

```
let bulkData = [];
foreach( user in users){
 bulkData.push(user);
}
await db.executeBulkInsertion(bulkData,[array of column names],[table name]);
```