# Dynamically building a SQL query (postgres and javascript)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vercel

I have a javascript function that needs to return a list of products. It's using postgres to retrieve the list of products. The function is passed a `categoryId` and an optional `typeId`. So I need to build a SQL query based on these.

Of course I could do something like this:

```js
async function getProducts(categoryId, typeId = false) {
  let products;
  if (typeId) {
    products = await sql`select * from products where categoryId=${categoryId} and typeId=${typeId}`
  }
  else {
    products = await sql`select * from products where categoryId=${categoryId}`
  }
  return products;
}
```

But how could I somehow dynamically "build" the SQL query with the template literals syntax?

Something like this:

```js
async function getProducts(categoryId, typeId = false) {
let query = `select * from products where categoryId=${categoryId}`;
if (typeId) {
  query += ` AND typeId=${typeId}`;
}
products = await sql`${query}` // doesn't work, so how could I generate a dynamic query like this?
return products;
}
```

(Note: this is using @vercel/postgres)

Comment: Does your second example not work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The second example doesn't work. When doing something like ``products = await sql`${query}``, it returns _syntax error at or near "$1"_

Comment: If it's all in one variable, `query`, do you even need the template literals? I'm not familiar with postgresql or vercel, but what about `products = await sql query;`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does require using the template literals syntax when running the query.

Comment: First, you need to end your SQL query with a semicolon so use `await sql\`${query};\``. Second, you might try inspecting your query before running it using `sqlTemplate` as shown in their tests: https://github.com/vercel/storage/blob/main/packages/postgres/src/sql-template.test.ts

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunatly adding a semicolon doesn't work either, even something simple like `let query = 'SELECT * FROM products'`

Comment: @TestWell The semicolon does not change anything; it's optional unless another statement follows in the same query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not documented by Vercel but their [*@vercel/postgres*](https://github.com/vercel/storage/tree/main/packages/postgres) package is just a tight wrapper around *@neondatabase/serverless* so you can use [their methods](https://github.com/neondatabase/serverless#pool-and-client) as well. The `` sql`…` ``, `` pool.sql`…` `` and `` client.sql`…` `` template tags cannot be used in any other way, they will throw an exception when not used with a template string. However, you can use the `.query()` method which takes the query test and the parameter values as separate arguments:

```
async function getProducts(categoryId, typeId) {
  let query = `select * from products where categoryId=$1`;
  let params = [categoryId];
  if (typeId != null) {
    query += ` AND typeId=$2`;
    params.push(typeId);
  }
  const products = await sql.query(query, params);
  return products;
}
```

Of course, building SQL strings manually is risky - it easily leads to syntax errors and SQL injection security vulnerabilities in your software. Make sure to *always* use parameterised queries and never interpolate dynamic values into your queries.

For common use cases (like dynamic conditions with various fields) consider using an ORM or query builder library instead, they come equipped with tried-and-tested helper functions for these things.

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick - thanks! I tried using Prisma and while it worked I found it painfully slow and also not very useful when having to build more complex queries. I have yet to find an ORM that justifies the additional overhead. Just my personal taste.

Comment: @Bergi, do you have an idea how bulk insertion would work ? I couldn't find an example within the docs. Thank you!

Comment: @Elnoor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008668/bulk-insert-into-postgres-with-brianc-node-postgres

Comment: @Bergi thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/77093839/5435780